# Float values not giving expected result in if statement using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Using MySQL, in using a trigger I am selecting float values and inserting them into  float declarations but when I try compare the two values in an if statement it does not seem to be able compare a float. After some slight research, I found some articles about a float bug when comparing a float in a if statement but there is no solution online that has worked as I would expect.

```
TRIGGER `Customer_Details`.`Client_Account_Payback_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `Client_Account_Payback` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


    declare amountPaid float;
    declare amountRamianing float;
    declare loanAmount float;

    select new.Client_Account_Payback_Amount into amountPaid;

    select Client_Account_Borrow_Amount_Remaining 
    from Client_Account_Borrow
    where Client_Account_Borrow_ID = new.Client_Account_Payback_Loan_Borrowed_ID
    into amountRamianing;

    select Client_Account_Amount_Borrowed
    from Client_Account_Borrow
    where Client_Account_Borrow_ID = new.Client_Account_Payback_Loan_Borrowed_ID
    into loanAmount;


    set amountRamianing = amountRamianing + amountPaid;

    IF amountRamianing > loanAmount THEN 
        UPDATE `Client_Account_Borrow`  
        SET `Client_Account_Borrow_Amount_Remaining` = amountRamianing 
        WHERE `Client_Account_Borrow_ID` = new.Client_Account_Payback_Loan_Borrowed_ID; 
    ELSE 
        UPDATE `Client_Account_Borrow` 
        SET `Client_Account_Borrow_Amount_Remaining` = amountRamianing, 
        `Client_Account_Borrow_Paid_Back` = true 
        WHERE `Client_Account_Borrow_ID` = new.Client_Account_Payback_Loan_Borrowed_ID; 
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Don't use FLOAT for money. Use DECIMAL, with the appropriate number of decimal places.

Comment: Or use `INT`, and scale the values by the smallest unit (e.g. pennies in US) (that's basically what DECIMAL does internally).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, is there anyway I can vote you up or something?